# Applying taxes ONLY to shipping cost for a specific country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm working for a non-profit and our WordPress website uses WooCommerce. We're not collecting taxes on the products prices.

We'd like **to apply taxes only on the shipping cost** when buyers are **shipping their order to Canada**.

For example, if someone from Canada buys a **`$20`** book, and shipping costs is **`$5`**, I want the tax to be calculated **`$5 * 15% = $0.75`** instead of what is does currently which is **`($20 + $5) * 15% = $3.75`**

I don't have enough php knowledge to make up a functional snippet to add in my child theme **`function.php`** file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer, as you will see below, is just about WooCommerce settings in your Admin Products Pages.

In your **Admin products List**, **Edit** a product. Go to the settings **`"Product Data"`** on **`"General"`** Tab. In **"Tax status"** selector, chose **`"Shipping only"`** option instead of **`"Taxable"`** option just as below:

[image]

Then **`"Update"`** your product. You are done. Now the tax will be applied only to the shipping, not to the product.

**You will need to do that for all products that need this option.**

---

**— Update —**

> **Finally this solution has worked for @johana**: "I entered taxes infos only for Canada, in the table in Woocommerce> settings> Tax> Standard. So taxes will only be applied to countries where I entered taxes informations, which is only Canada."…

Comment: Thank you so much Loic !! Your solution worked, because I entered taxes infos only for Canada, in the table in Woocommerce> settings> Tax> Standard. So taxes will only be applied to countries where I entered taxes informations, which is only Canada.

Comment: @Johanna Perfect :) Very Happy it worked, just with woocommerce settings… See you around next time.